# Openfire Privacy Lists not working for item of type 'group' and custom user/group from another DB

Tags: java, xmpp, openfire

I've been stuck on this for almost a week and decided I needed an extra help.

I have already made custom user/groups data integration with external database, and it works fine, all users and groups from my custom DB are showing on admin panel of Openfire. The problem is when I try to set up a privacy list for any user with an  of type 'group'.

Example:

```
<iq from='romeo@example.net/orchard' type='set' id='msg2'>
<query xmlns='jabber:iq:privacy'>
  <list name='message-group-example'>
    <item type='group'  // IF I use 'jid' here, it works fine. But when I use 'group', it does not.
          value='Enemies'  
          action='deny'
          order='4'>
    </item>
  </list>
</query>
</iq>
```

I'm getting this error on error.log:

```
2015.05.05 10:09:19 org.jivesoftware.openfire.group.JDBCGroupProvider - Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).
java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).
  at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1084)
  at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:987)
  at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:973)
  at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:918)
  at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.checkBounds(PreparedStatement.java:3688)
  at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.setInternal(PreparedStatement.java:3670)
  at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.setString(PreparedStatement.java:4491)
  at org.jivesoftware.openfire.group.JDBCGroupProvider.getMembers(JDBCGroupProvider. java:177)
  at org.jivesoftware.openfire.group.JDBCGroupProvider.getGroup(JDBCGroupProvider.ja va:155)
  at org.jivesoftware.openfire.group.GroupManager.getGroup(GroupManager.java:343)
  at org.jivesoftware.openfire.group.GroupManager.getGroup(GroupManager.java:320)
  at org.jivesoftware.openfire.group.GroupCollection$GroupIterator.getNextElement(Gr oupCollection.java:113)
  at org.jivesoftware.openfire.group.GroupCollection$GroupIterator.hasNext(GroupColl ection.java:76)
  at org.jivesoftware.openfire.roster.RosterManager.getSharedGroups(RosterManager.ja va:191)
  at org.jivesoftware.openfire.roster.Roster.<init>(Roster.java:128)
  at org.jivesoftware.openfire.roster.RosterManager.getRoster(RosterManager.java:116 )
  at org.jivesoftware.openfire.handler.PresenceUpdateHandler.broadcastUpdate(Presenc eUpdateHandler.java:307)
  at org.jivesoftware.openfire.handler.PresenceUpdateHandler.process(PresenceUpdateH andler.java:162)
  at org.jivesoftware.openfire.handler.PresenceUpdateHandler.process(PresenceUpdateH andler.java:137)
  at org.jivesoftware.openfire.handler.PresenceUpdateHandler.process(PresenceUpdateH andler.java:201)
  at org.jivesoftware.openfire.PresenceRouter.handle(PresenceRouter.java:148)
  at org.jivesoftware.openfire.PresenceRouter.route(PresenceRouter.java:84)
  at org.jivesoftware.openfire.spi.PacketRouterImpl.route(PacketRouterImpl.java:84)
  at org.jivesoftware.openfire.net.StanzaHandler.processPresence(StanzaHandler.java: 348)
  at org.jivesoftware.openfire.net.ClientStanzaHandler.processPresence(ClientStanzaH andler.java:100)
  at org.jivesoftware.openfire.net.StanzaHandler.process(StanzaHandler.java:265)
  at org.jivesoftware.openfire.net.StanzaHandler.process(StanzaHandler.java:187)
  at org.jivesoftware.openfire.nio.ConnectionHandler.messageReceived(ConnectionHandl er.java:189)
  at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain$TailFilter.messageReceive d(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:854)
  at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.callNextMessageReceived(D efaultIoFilterChain.java:542)
  at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.access$6(DefaultIoFilterC hain.java:538)
  at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain$EntryImpl$1.messageReceiv ed(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:943)
  at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.IoFilterAdapter.messageReceived(IoFilterAdapte r.java:109)
  at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.callNextMessageReceived(D efaultIoFilterChain.java:542)
  at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.access$6(DefaultIoFilterC hain.java:538)
  at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain$EntryImpl$1.messageReceiv ed(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:943)
  at org.apache.mina.filter.codec.ProtocolCodecFilter$ProtocolDecoderOutputImpl.flus h(ProtocolCodecFilter.java:405)
  at org.apache.mina.filter.codec.ProtocolCodecFilter.messageReceived(ProtocolCodecF ilter.java:235)
  at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.callNextMessageReceived(D efaultIoFilterChain.java:542)
  at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.access$6(DefaultIoFilterC hain.java:538)
  at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain$EntryImpl$1.messageReceiv ed(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:943)
  at org.apache.mina.filter.ssl.SslHandler.flushScheduledEvents(SslHandler.java:319)
  at org.apache.mina.filter.ssl.SslFilter.messageReceived(SslFilter.java:520)
  at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.callNextMessageReceived(D efaultIoFilterChain.java:542)
  at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.access$6(DefaultIoFilterC hain.java:538)
  at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain$EntryImpl$1.messageReceiv ed(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:943)
  at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.IoFilterEvent.fire(IoFilterEvent.java:74)
  at org.apache.mina.core.session.IoEvent.run(IoEvent.java:63)
  at org.apache.mina.filter.executor.OrderedThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Ordere dThreadPoolExecutor.java:769)
  at org.apache.mina.filter.executor.OrderedThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTasks(Order edThreadPoolExecutor.java:761)
  at org.apache.mina.filter.executor.OrderedThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(OrderedThr eadPoolExecutor.java:703)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I tried setting the privacy list both by XML stanzas and Openfire 'ofprivacylist' database table directly. I have already cleaned all caches and checked my SQL statements on 'ofproperty' table but everything seems correct. I'm using Openfire 3.10 and testing with PSI and PSI+ XMPP Clients.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The problem still occurs, but the log message is now fixed. It was missing a '?' in my custom dbcGroupProvider.descriptionSQL SQL.

it was:

```
SELECT name FROM 
    (select u.id as uid FROM animati_users u WHERE u.username) as tmp
        INNER JOIN 
    animati_chat_users_groups user_chat_groups
        ON 
    tmp.uid=user_chat_groups.user_id
        INNER JOIN
    animati_chat_groups cg
        ON
    cg.id=group_id
```

and now:

```
    SELECT name FROM 
        (select u.id as uid FROM animati_users u WHERE u.username = ?) 
as tmp
            INNER JOIN 
        animati_chat_users_groups user_chat_groups
            ON 
        tmp.uid=user_chat_groups.user_id
            INNER JOIN
        animati_chat_groups cg
            ON
        cg.id=group_id
```

You can see that the diference is here: **WHERE u.username = ?**